# How to trigger an html button (linked to some javascript) WITHOUT using selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, bots

I'm currently working on a bot to automate a buying process on a NFT project.
Until now, I was using `selenium` in order to automate the process by loading specific pages, clicking buttons, filling passwords, etc...
Everything was working fine except that it was **too long** and I needed something really faster to solve my problem.
I was using headless browser and I disabled image loading, but nothing made the process fast enough.

At the begining of the project, I wanted to perform the buying process using **only requests** but it was not possible since I needed to provide a "signature" inside the payload of the request, including some hashes that I'm not able to create/find (blockchain stuff).

So here is my question:

- **Is there a way to download/get an HTML page including its javascript in order to trigger the button that performs the buying process ?**

It must be fast and I need to be logged in to access the page.

Thank you !

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website

Comment: Though download all html and js files, from the website crawler tool would be stopped. I have tried to execute macro tool on a website but it was stopped.

Comment: HTMLUnit is much faster... worth a try.

Comment: HTMLUnit doesn't work, I don't know why.
I downloaded the version of the selenium standalone server corresponding to my selenium installed version, but when I try to connect to it it always timeouts for no reason ...